# How do I setup Cucumber with Grails 3.2.4 for Testing with Grails?

Tags: testing, grails, cucumber, bdd

I've been trying to do BDD testing with Grails 3.2.4 and I've had difficulty integrating Cucumber(https://cucumber.io/) with Grails 3.2. If it can be done then how do I setup cucumber for testing?

I've tried setting up with gradle cucumber but it doesn't seem to be working properly and there isn't much of a guide to getting it setup. See https://github.com/samueltbrown/gradle-cucumber-plugin for gradle cucumber and https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber for Grails cucumber which is not compatible with Grails 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you are able to use Java libraries. Looking in the docs tells me that it is possible to use [JUnit](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html) for unit testing.

This leads me to think that you should be able to use the [Java Skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton) provided by the Cucumber team.

My approach would be to clone it and get it to run. It should run out of the box. Then include it in your test suite for your project.

Answer (score 0):

I've got cucumber to work with just a dummy test class (not a Grails domain class), but when I try to test a real domain class to make sure the attribute constraints are adhered to, it doesn't work.  The class is not seen as a domain class and I'm told GORM has not been initialized. I'll be one step closer to getting Cucumber to work with Grails 3 once I find out how to initialize GORM in the Cucumber step defintions.